# Clicking Update in the EditCommandColumn of an ASP.NET DataGrid does not initiate the Click event defined in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that receives data from several tables in an Entity Data Model.I used an EditCommandColumn to provide editing of the data as well as TemplateColumns that are bound to the columns of a Function Import from a Stored Procedure on the database.

Here is the portion of the .aspx code for the creation of the asp:DataGrid

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="gridUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="vertical-align: top; height:250px; overflow:auto; width:1800px;">
            <asp:DataGrid ID="dgdEditQ" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
                    BackColor="AntiqueWhite" BorderColor="Green" BorderStyle="Ridge" 
                    CellPadding="10" Font-Bold="True"
                    Font-Size="Large" Width="1800px" Height="250px" OnEditCommand="dgdEditQ_Edit"
                    OnCancelCommand="dgdEditQ_Cancel" OnUpdateCommand="dgdEditQ_Update"
                    CellSpacing="10" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" 
                    ItemStyle-Width="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                <AlternatingItemStyle />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:EditCommandColumn
                            EditText="Edit"
                            CancelText="Cancel"
                            UpdateText="Update"
                            HeaderText="Edit item"
                            ButtonType="LinkButton">
                    </asp:EditCommandColumn>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="true">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <b> Quote Number </b>
                        </HeaderTemplate>   
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuoteNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>                                                          
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <b> Name </b>
                        </HeaderTemplate>   
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEdN"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' ID="txbEdName" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txbEdName" ErrorMessage="The name of the quote is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </EditItemTemplate>                                                          
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <b> Street </b>
                    </HeaderTemplate>   
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEdSt"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Street") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Street") %>' ID="txbEdStreet" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>                                                          
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <b> City & State </b>
                    </HeaderTemplate>   
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEdCS"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CityState") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CityState") %>' ID="txbEdCS" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>                                                         
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

                </Columns>
                <SelectedItemStyle />
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click Edit in the EditCommandColumn that works everytime and the Cancel does as well, but the Update button click never triggers the onclick eventhandler in my code behind:

```
protected void dgdEditQ_Update(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridItem dgi = dgdEditQ.SelectedItem;
        TextBox[] myBoxes = new TextBox[26];
        string[] myParams = new string[26];

        myBoxes[0] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Quote Number");
        myBoxes[1] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Name");
        myBoxes[2] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Street");
        myBoxes[3] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("City & State");
        myBoxes[4] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Type of Quote");
        myBoxes[5] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("List Provided By");
        myBoxes[6] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Estimator");
        myBoxes[7] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Date Received");
        myBoxes[8] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Date Due");
        myBoxes[9] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Date of Plans");
        myBoxes[10] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Date of Revision");
        myBoxes[11] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Revision #");
        myBoxes[12] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Plan Name");
        myBoxes[13] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Customer");
        myBoxes[14] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Amount");
        myBoxes[15] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Quote Status");
        myBoxes[16] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Excel File");
        myBoxes[17] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Folder Location");
        myBoxes[18] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Architect");
        myBoxes[19] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Architectural Firm");
        myBoxes[20] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Architect's Phone");
        myBoxes[21] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Architect's Fax");
        myBoxes[22] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Engineer");
        myBoxes[23] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Engineering Firm");
        myBoxes[24] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Engineer's Phone");
        myBoxes[25] = (TextBox)dgi.FindControl("Engineer's Fax");

        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            myParams[j] = myBoxes[j].Text;
        }
    }
```

I am fairly, new to ASP.NET but all the research I have done thus far has not provided me with answer to why my Update event is not firing when I click the Update button.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with this code...

Comment: Have you put a break point in your code and verified that it is not actually being called or are you thinking it is not working because the UI is not updated with changes?

Comment: I have a breakpoint in the code and it never reaches the breakpoint

Comment: Could you post code the Edit event

Answer (score 1):

Even if your event handler is firing, it will not actually update anything, because all you are doing is storing the text value of each text box into a string array and then not saving it anywhere, nor are you updating the UI (i.e. rebinding the grid).

You need to have logic similar to this in your handler:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
{
    myParams[j] = myBoxes[j].Text;
}

// Send myParams string array to some logic that will save it (i.e. database)

// Rebind the grid so that the changes will be reflected to the user once they exit edit mode
dgdEditQ.DataSource = GetDataFromDatabase();
dgdEditQ.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you I added code to update the database and to my call my rebinding method

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your probleme and I have find it remove : ViewStateMode="Disabled"

Comment: I removed the ViewStateMode="Disabled" from my code and it still does not fire the Update eventr

Comment: I copy/past your code and i have same behavior. When i delete ViewStateMode="Disabled" the Update event is firing. 
In your Edit event do you re-databinding the datagrid ?

Comment: you have placed an asp validator on TemplateColumn and setting visibility property to false, are you sure that "Name" member  value contains something.  it's not display if requiert a validation

Comment: Changed visibility to true and it still will not fire the update

Comment: protected void dgdEditQ_Edit(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            quoteToEdit = txbQN.Text;        
            

             dgdEditQ.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
             DataBinder(myPage.MyKey);
        }                                                            This is the edit event